# self-teaching sql, grouping results error

Tags: sql, oracle

Teaching myself SQL, and using an employee info db, on oracle 11g.

I'm trying to return the total numbers of hours and days worked by an employee at each of the "offices"

However, the "work hours" returns the correct time of each employees shift, but as individual rows, instead of having one row with total number of days and total number of hours. (This means each row has number of days = 1)

```
SELECT L.OFFICE_NAME as "Shop", 
(us.LAST_NAME || ' , ' || us.FIRST_NAME) AS "Employee Name",
COUNT(distinct shift.shift_date) as "WORK DAYS",
round((shift2.MaxSignOffTime-shift.MinSignOnTime)*24, 1) AS "WORK HOURS",

FROM 
LOCAL_OFFICE L
JOIN 
    Orders ord
    ON L.LOCAL_OFFICE_ID = ord.LOCAL_OFFICE_ID
JOIN  
    USERS us
    ON
     us.USER_ID = ord.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID
join
    (SELECT min(act_sign_dt) as MinSignOnTime, USER_ID, shift_token 
FROM CLIENT_SIGN 
WHERE
    BEG_OF_SHIFT = 'Y'
GROUP BY shift_date, user_id, shift_token)  shift on shift. user_id = ord.assigned_to_user_id
join
    (SELECT max(act_sign_dt) as MaxSignOffTime, USER_ID, shift_token 
FROM CLIENT_SIGN 
WHERE
    end_OF_SHIFT = 'Y'
GROUP BY shift_date, user_id, shift_token)  shift2 on shift2.shift_token = shift.shift_token

GROUP BY OFFICE_NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME,shift.shift_date, (shift2.MaxSignOffTime-shift.MinSignOnTime)
ORDER BY OFFICE_NAME, "Employee Name"
```

I'm willing to answer any questions needed, but I simply cannot see why it is not grouping into one row for each employee for each office location

Comment: can you not make a simpler test case? It is also a good practice to learn to abstract/simplify a problem (Me atleast have no energy to learn all that long query...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

Put a Sum() around this in the SELECT:

```
round((shift2.MaxSignOffTime-shift.MinSignOnTime)*24, 1)
```

and remove this:

```
(shift2.MaxSignOffTime-shift.MinSignOnTime)
```

from the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Oh wow that was it. Thank you so much for taking the time to read through all that.